# How to show an alert or toaster message when the JWT token expires in Angular 7

Tags: javascript, angular, angular7, angular-http-interceptors

When a JWT token expires, the web app should show an `alert` or modal pop up, then it should redirect to login page. Currently I am using toaster message.

I have many api calls in my component. I get many toaster messages 'token expired'. I should show a message only and redirect to login page. tell me your good idea. I have some articles in the internet. But I could not get those things clearly.

```
import {
    HttpEvent,
    HttpInterceptor,
    HttpHandler,
    HttpRequest,
    HttpResponse,
    HttpErrorResponse
   } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable, throwError } from 'rxjs';
import { retry, catchError } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { ToastrManager } from 'ng6-toastr-notifications';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { JwtDecoderService } from './jwt-decoder.service';

@Injectable()
export class HttpErrorInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {

    constructor(public router: Router,
                public toastr: ToastrManager,
                private jwtDecoder: JwtDecoderService, ) {
    }

    intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
      if (localStorage.getItem('isLoggedin') === 'false' && !this.jwtDecoder.isTokenExpired()) {
        this.toastr.warningToastr('Token expired');
        return;
      }
      return next.handle(request)
        .pipe(
          catchError((error: HttpErrorResponse) => {
            let errorMessage = '';
            if (error.error instanceof ErrorEvent) {
              // client-side error
              errorMessage = `Error: ${error.error.message}`;
            } else {
              // server-side error
              errorMessage = `Error Code: ${error.status}\nMessage: ${error.message}`;
              if (error.status === 404) {
                this.toastr.warningToastr('Server Not Found');
                this.router.navigate(['/login']);
              }
              if (error.status === 412) {
                this.toastr.warningToastr('Token expired');
                this.router.navigate(['/login']);
              }
              // if (error.status === 500 || error.status === 400) {
              //   this.toastr.errorToastr('We encountered a technical issue');
              // }
            }
            // return throwError(errorMessage);
            return throwError(error);
          })
        );
    }
   }
```

Comment: Why don't use `router.navigate` in your first branch, instead of just `return`? The cleaner way would be to factor out this behaviour in a specific service, this way you always call the same behavior, instead of duplicating it in several branches.

Comment: Since all your APIs use JWT token for authentication, it may be a good idea to first check the validity of the token and then proceeds for other APIs calls.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use **HttpInterceptor**. Since every API call passes trough interceptor, you can check if the token is still valid, proceed with the API call

If the token expired, show toastr alert and prevent any further API call.

For more info on using interceptor, visit this [10 ways to use Interceptors](https://blog.angularindepth.com/top-10-ways-to-use-interceptors-in-angular-db450f8a62d6)  and [Angular 7 JWT Interceptor](https://jasonwatmore.com/post/2018/11/16/angular-7-jwt-authentication-example-tutorial)

> Complete Code:

**http-interceptor.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpInterceptor, HttpRequest, HttpHandler, HttpEvent, HttpResponse } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { tap } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { SessionService } from './session.service';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { throwError } from 'rxjs';

declare var toastr;

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class HttpInterceptorService implements HttpInterceptor {

  constructor(private router: Router, private sessionService: SessionService) { }

  intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    var token = this.sessionService.getToken();
    if (token != null && this.sessionService.isTokenExpired()) {
      this.sessionService.logOut()
      toastr.warning("Session Timed Out! Please Login");
      this.router.navigate(['/login'])
      return throwError("Session Timed Out")
    } else {

      const authRquest = req.clone({
        setHeaders: {
          Authorization: 'Bearer ' + token
        }
      })
      return next.handle(authRquest)
        .pipe(
          tap(event => {
          }, error => {
          })
        )
    }

  }
}
```

**app.module.ts**

```
 providers: [
    {
        provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
        useClass: HttpInterceptorService,
        multi: true
      }
   ]
```

**session-service.ts**

```
  getToken(): string {
    return localStorage.getItem('userToken');
  }

  getTokenExpirationDate(token: string): Date {
    token = this.getToken()
    const decoded = jwt_decode(token);

    if (decoded.exp === undefined) return null;

    const date = new Date(0);
    date.setUTCSeconds(decoded.exp);
    return date;
  }

  isTokenExpired(token?: string): boolean {
    if (!token) token = this.getToken();
    if (!token) return true;

    const date = this.getTokenExpirationDate(token);
    if (date === undefined) return false;
    return !(date.valueOf() > new Date().valueOf());
  }

  logOut(loginType?: string) {
    localStorage.removeItem('isLoggedin');
    localStorage.removeItem('userRole');

  }
```

Comment: i have a doubt. do the apicalls go only through the interceptor ? or There are many libraries and images i get form the cloud. i mean from the internet. so do the images and libraries such as boostrap, jquery go through the interceptor ????

Comment: Only API calls. You can set authentication token, display loader etc through interceptor. If you add interceptor, all API calls will pass through it

Comment: @GeorgKastenhofer https://www.npmjs.com/package/jwt-decode